# Как в IIS на windows настроить несколько виртуальных хостов?

Tags: windows, iis, virtual-hosts

При установки IIS на windows был указан путь для корневого каталога сайта c:\web. Необходимо настроить несколько виртуальных хостов для сайтов, расположенных в c:\web\site1 и c:\web\site2, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

[Ссылка](http://www.visualwin.com/Host-Header/) на пошаговую инструкцию (вам необходим шаг с указанием "Web Site Home Directory" при добавлении нового сайт).